# What is the type of the parameters being passed into this function

Tags: c++, parameters

I have found a function in a library in c++ and I can't tell the types of the parameters being passed in and just so my knowledge and understanding is complete it would be good for me to know.

To me they look like arrays of function pointers but without the *, am I right in my assumption?

```
template < typename _Tp , size_t _Nm > 
inline void swap ( _Tp ( & __a ) [ _Nm ] , _Tp ( & __b ) [ _Nm ] )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The types of both arguments are the same. They are references to arrays of length `_Nm` where each element is of type `_Tp`. The type of the elements and length of the arrays must match in both arguments. Consider the similarity between the types of those arguments and the type of arrRef in the following example:

```
int arr1[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int (&arrRef)[5] = arr1; // arrRef is a reference to arr1
```

For example, if we have the following:

```
int arr1[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int arr2[] = {6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
swap(arr1, arr2);
```

We instantiate a version of `swap` with the signature `void swap(int (&)[5], int (&)[5])`.

Answer (score 2):

They're references to arrays of object type `_Tp` and size `_Nm`.

The right way to read a C or C++ type is that declaration reflects use.  `_Tp ( & __a ) [ _Nm ]` says that given a variable `__a` of that type you can write `(__a)[n]`, with `0 <= n < _Nm`, and attain an object of type `_Tp`.  The presence of the `&` type modifier works by analogy with the `*` modifier; a variable declared as `_Tp ( * __a ) [ _Nm ]` would be a pointer to an array, since you could write `(*__a)[n]`.